# there isn't any way to add border radius to a button in the current Button() class.Is there any attribute for adding a border radius in pythonTkinter?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

After i did this code i saw the stack overflow's answers given by some developers and i was really confused that i needed to make custom classes and that wasn't really easy. Can please anyone tell me any parameter of Button() Class that is like other parameters like text=" " , root and many other parameters?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Window")
root.geometry("600x700")
btn1 = Button(root,text="Some text")# I am confused as i don't know how to add border radius in a Button Class
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry everyone i actually forgot to pack() the btn1

Comment: It is not possible by default. Though you can create your own buttons

Comment: _"Can please anyone tell me any parameter of Button() Class that is like other parameters like text=" " , root and many other parameters?"_ - there is no such parameter.